# Javascript for clicking a button on a page which loads after every few minutes

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am looking for a tampermonkey/greasemonkey script which clicks on a button specified by its classname. This button loads after every two minutes on the page. I need this button to get clicked automatically as it loads.

className: " btn btn-success "

I tried (please fix my code and explain):

```
function (){
$('.btn btn-success').onLoad("click")}
```

I tried using this, but couldn't reach so far:

```
document.getElementByClassName("btn btn-success").onLoad();
```

So, here's an update to the button elements. 
When the button is active/enabled:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="refreshLine();"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Yes</button>
```

When it's inactive/disabled:

```
<button class="btn popover-btn btn-success disabled" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="You can press this button in 1min 25s "><i class="icon-ok"></i> Yes</button>
```

That "You can press button in...." is the timer.
Help me out. I am completely new to this.

*Problem Solved: 
@user3173842 solved my problem though, he asked me to setInterval to the function "refreshLine()" as given in the active button code. I used `setInterval(refreshLine, 1000)`. So it does the refreshLine function every 1 second. The button pops up, refreshLine is executed and the button is pushed. Thank you for help @user3173842.*

Comment: `window.onload = function(){ $('.btn .btn-success').trigger("click"); }`

Comment: So, will this click the button as soon as it loads itself after two minutes?

Comment: @Divyansh_C, It will trigger click every time `onload` handler is called..

Comment: When you write `$.onLoad()` you're registering the `onLoad` event to the element you use it on. So in your example you're registering the `onLoad` event to a button. You probably do not want this, you want to register it to the page so that after it is done loading, it triggers a click for the button. Therefor you need to register the `onLoad` to the `window` object like Rayon Dabre does. In the handler of this event you specify what  you want to do, namely trigger a click for the button.

Comment: @Divyansh_C you could modify Rayon Dabres answer by setting a timeout (a javascript built in function) for 2 minutes, that then triggers the click. Just google around a bit to find the syntax for this, it's really easy.

Comment: @Glubus, My guess is `.trigger('click')` will submit and refresh the page and `onload` event is invoked..May be this is what OP is seeking..

Comment: I want to click the button, as the button loads, and not page. The page contains a button which needs to be clicked after every two minutes to tell the page that I'm active.

Comment: btw `$('.btn .btn-success')` not `$('.btn btn-success')`

Comment: @Divyansh_C so the button is loaded way after the page is loaded? Or at least the button is not part of the page as it loads?

Comment: @Glubus Yep, the button loads again and again(with interval of two mintues) after the page loads.

Comment: @Divyansh_C oops I guess I should've seen that in your question. Though, key is *after the page loads*, so the pageload is leading in the sense that if you catch the pageload, you can set a timeout of 2 minutes that triggers the click after it is done. so: `window.onload = function(){ setTimeout(function() {$('.btn .btn-success').trigger("click"); }, 2 * 60 * 1000)};`

Comment: Actually, the button gets replaced by a disabled button and after two minutes, the active button again comes up.
The disabled button's class is "btn popover-btn btn-success disabled"

Should I add this to the question?

Comment: Does the button really get replaced or is it the same button and only classes are toggled?

Comment: I believe you're right, the classes are toggled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content containing the button gets refreshed and you want to click the button every time:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       example
// @version    0.1
// @match      http:// PASTE URL HERE
// @include    http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var clickedButton;
(function checkButton() {
  var btn=$('.yes .btn.popover-btn.btn-success');
  if (!btn.length || btn[0]===clickedButton) {
    setTimeout(checkButton, 200);
    return;
  }
  clickedButton=btn[0];
  btn.click();
})();
```

If there are new buttons appended every time you can store and check for btn.length and click new buttons this way.

Comment: I am actually new to the tampermonkey scripts, so do I have to paste it as it is? Or add something more?
I tried putting the codes separately in two different scripts, and they don't seem to work.

Comment: Based on the details you provided the second snippet should work as it is - since you are using the $ sign in your question I assumed you have included jQuery or zepto.

Comment: These codes are clicking all the buttons on the page. Am I making some mistake?

Comment: All buttons having the `btn` and `btn-success` class. I am working on an updated example based on the details you provided within the last few minutes.

Comment: Should I give more details about the button?

Comment: So I grabbed the button elements:

Comment: When disabled:
    <button class="btn popover-btn btn-success disabled" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="You can press this button in 1min 25s "><i class="icon-ok"></i> Yes</button>

Comment: When enabled:
    
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="refreshLine();"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Yes</button>

Comment: try my second snippet from this answer with the header (comments) from my other answer. if this does not work either there could be a mechanism preventing what you are trying to do or you might have missed something relevant. in this case I'm afraid we wont be able to help.

Comment: Umm, so can you help me with the "refreshline();" ?
Like, doing this "refreshline();" after every time it's available?
Do I need to create a separate post for this?

Comment: it's `refreshLine` - js names are case sensitive. you could try what happens if you just say `setInterval(refreshLine, 121000);`

Answer (score 0):

Since you changed the requirements in your comments:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       example
// @version    0.1
// @match      http:// PASTE URL HERE
// @include    http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var lastState=false;
setInterval(function checkButton() {
  var btn=$('.btn.popover-btn.btn-success'), state;
  if (!btn.length) {
    return;
  }
  state=!btn.hasClass('disabled');
  if (lastState!=state && state) {
    btn.click();
  }
  lastState=state;
}, 500);
```

This will select the button(s) with `btn popover-btn btn-success` and store if it has the disabled class. Everytime the disabled class gets removed the button will be clicked. If there are too many buttons affected you can check the parent elements of the button you want to click for the `id` property and use `var btn=$('#popover .btn.popover-btn.btn-success')` for example, if you see `id="popover"`.

Comment: Tried your second snippet with this one, it again, clicks all the buttons.

Comment: Then try to add the id of an parent element to the selector like I proposed.

Comment: it's under   <div class="yes">

Comment: I edited my other answer, if this does not work I give up (after 2 hours!) since there are definitely some relevant details missing.

Comment: I did ' setInterval(refreshLine, 1000) ' and now it's working perfectly, thanks  for you answers and help. I'll work on your other codes as soon as I get used to them. Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: I do not think it would be appropriate to publish a script that does something against the will of the website operator, especially since it was linked here. - Edit: thanks for removing the link.

Comment: Yeah I thought the same thing, that's why I didn't want to reveal the link.
That setInterval code worked. Thanks again!